# can any one let me know how to disable the navigationbar in titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

can any one let me know how to disable(not to hide) the navigation bar in titanium.

Thanks in Advance,
Swathi.

Answer (score 0):

I think this URL will help you to hide action bar
[hide action bar](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/08/hiding-the-android-actionbar/)

or if you are work with classic app development

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({theme: "Theme.NoActionBar"});
win.open();
```

and for alloy

```
win1.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
    win1.activity.actionBar.hide();
});
win1.open();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply VRK, but I need to disable the navigation bar rather than hiding it.

Comment: @Swathi you can edit the xml contents for disable nav bar please follow the method 2 of link which I provided

Comment: May I know how to implement this for IOS?